# conditional formatting in excel using c#

Tags: formatting, conditional-statements

I have an excel sheet with some values in the cells (range as u8:u1260). Cell values range from -100 to 100. I want to add conditional formatting where values >=20 and <=-20 should be highlighted in red with bold font. I tried the below code but it's not working.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range = ws.get_Range("u8", "ab1260");
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.FormatConditions fcs = range.FormatConditions;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.FormatCondition fc = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.FormatCondition)fcs.Add
                (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFormatConditionType.xlExpression, Type.Missing, "=$u$8:$ab$1260 >= 20");
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Interior interior = fc.Interior;
            interior.Color = ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.Red);
```

Comment: What does "It's not working" mean? Can you be more specific about the error?

Comment: i dont see any formating being done after executing the code

Comment: any answers for this